# Java array.add() stops the program

Tags: java, arrays, element, addition, continue

I managed to dynamically add an element in my array, but unfortunately the program stops. How can I continue it? Thank you!

....

```
List<String> messages = Arrays.asList("Mary", "Nadia!", "Drake");

System.out.println("Enter Costumer's Name:"); 
cust_name =in.next();
if(cust_name .equals("Mary"))
System.out.println("Already a member!");
else if (cust_name .equals("Nadia"))
System.out.println("Already a member!");
else if(cust_name .equals("Drake"))
System.out.println("Already a member!");
else
messages.add(in.next());
System.out.println("Not a member! " + cust_name + " just added.");
```

....

Comment: When you program stops, it should tell you what went wrong. There will be an exception with description and a stack trace. Please post the errors.

Comment: stacktrace required, also instead of checking hardcoded for each element you should check `if(messages.contains(cust_name))`

Comment: An alternative to what you're doing here is to use a `Set<String>` (such as `HashSet`) to store the name.  When you add something to a `Set`, the value returned is a `boolean`, which tells you whether the value is actually new - and you could print the appropriate message depending on that value.  It will make your code shorter and cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Arrays.asList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) returns a fixed size `List`, the easiest fix I can think of is -

```
List<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>(
    Arrays.asList("Mary", "Nadia!", "Drake")
); // Creates a new (mutable) list.
```

Answer (score 2):

The `List` that `Arrays.asList` returns is fixed size. Trying to add to it will result in an exception.

If you want a dynamic list initialized to some values then do something like:

```
List<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Mary", "Nadia!", "Drake"));
```

Or better yet use [Google Guava's `Lists.newArrayList`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#newArrayList%28E...%29)

```
List<String> messages = Lists.newArrayList("Mary", "Nadia!", "Drake");
```

Comment: I don't think so http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29

Comment: Oops answer edited :) , initially it said it returns immutable instance and can't be modified